# ADF Pipeline to delete certain folders/subfolders based on regex

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have several folders in azure storage explorer under this form.

```
batch-input/bab/20203042_000000/**files
batch-input/bab/20202314_000000/**files
batch-input/bab/20211212_000000/**files
batch_input/aba/20203212_000000/**files
...
```

I am trying to create a pipeline in azure data factory to delete certain folders and everything inside them based on several user parameters. Currently I have a Delete activity linked to the corresponding dataset, with the container name: batch-input.

So far so good, but the part I'm having trouble with is the FolderAndSubFolderName value. I tried this:

```
@concat(pipeline().parameters.ParamDomain, '/', pipeline().parameters.ParamDate, '*')
```

The `ParamDomain` in this case would be `bab` for example and `ParamDate` would be `2020`.

In theory this would be able to delete the 2 folders and all the files within from the exaple I posted above. In practive what happens is that when I check the execution I see this as my parameter value instead:

`"folderPath": "batch-input/bab/2020^*"`

I'm not sure where the '^' comes from and tried multiple ways to remove it but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the `*` in the absolute file path, better to go with one additional parameter declared in the dataset for the wild card i.e. `*`, and use it separately in **file_name** section instead of concatenating it.

[image]